# pin position - Slider pin position issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a slider with three posts using PHP and WordPress. Now, I want to replace the most recent post with one of the existing posts. How do I do it?

```
<?php

for ($cnt2 = 1; $cnt2 <= 2; $cnt2++) {
    $pin_to = get_post_meta($latest_post_array [$cnt2] ["id"], 'pin_to', true);
    $pin_at = get_post_meta($latest_post_array [$cnt2] ["id"], 'pin_slider_no', true);
    if ($pin_at == "s0" || $pin_at == "") {
        $popupvideoads2 = "N";
    } else {
        if ($pin_to > $today) {
            $popupvideoads2 = "Y";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about the objects you're referring to - I'm pretty sure people can't understand what do you mean by `Slider No.5`, `to pin one news post`, `next post`, and so on.

Comment: I edited again, may you check please

Comment: You still don't explain what is the 'Slider' you're referring to.

Comment: It is a news content slider with image, when it is clicked then It will open the full page. Similar to this one: [link](http://wowslider.com/rq/php-slideshow/)